# Can I restart a docker container listed in the docker ps -a output?

Tags: docker

The first time I ran my configured image, I passed in a `--name` option. After running the image, I stopped it. Now, it appears in the `docker ps` output:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/docker$ docker ps -a
```

Since it has a name, how can I restart it? It seems that the `docker run` command only accepts an imageid (not a containerid). And if run it again, a new container is created (which is not what I want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a stopped container one could issue

```
docker start {name}
```